# UIScrollView's subviews layout wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I add some UIButtons to UIScrollView and set their coordinate in Interface Builder.But when I run app,the buttons are a little below the right position.I set the UIScrollView's and UIButtons' autoresizing to up and left.And I did't use autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Set all the autoresizing constraints of  UIScrollView and remove the UIButton's up and left autoresizing constraints. This will probably make UIButtons to take their relative positions as they were set in interface builder. I have not tried it, but hope will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Select the button and set all individually like this with right frame

[image]